Geometry optimization with background charges in Gaussian with charge keyword
Gaussian requires the opt=z-matrix option when performing geometry optimization with the charge keyword. As can be seen in the following section from Gaussian's website:

To perform geometry optimizations in the presence of background
charges, you must use Opt=Z-Matrix NoSymm keywords and define the
input geometry either in traditional Z-matrix coordinates or symbolic
Cartesian coordinates

Why is it not possible to use the charge keyword with the default settings (redundant internal coordinates)? Is there a theoretical or practical problem in doing this? I could not understand exactly what the charge keyword does. Does it only include the Coulomb potential of the background charges?
For example, would the charge keyword be sufficient to include the Madelung potential in the optimization of ionic crystal structures (if we consider that all the charges are determined by Ewald summation or an appropriate method)?

Have you tried turning it off and then back on again? Using the ReadGeom keyword to restart from the last geometry will restart from the last converged geometry which might work. If not, Orca can handle complex scenarios (such as your background charges) more elegantly than Gaussian.

This is interesting as the Z-matrix coordinate is so well-known that it fails to handle canonical systems like ring systems.
